# Partial autocorrelation significant at regular lag distance

Tags: forecasting, autoregressive, seasonality, acf-pacf, macroeconomics

I am trying to forecast inflation with a simple AR model.
I took the natural logarithm of the CPI and subtracted the 12th lag, thus obtaining a measure of inflation.
The PACF is significant at the first lag, and then at the 13th and at the 25th lag (in both cases positive). How should I interpret this?

I would exclude seasonality, as differencing over one year should remove yearly seasonal patterns. I considered that there may be a longer cycle, probably a business cycle.
However, if this consideration is correct, given that the length of the business cycle is not fixed, I am not sure how should I deal with it in the context of a simple AR model.

I also considered that it may be just a case. I checked the PACF of a couple of subsamples of the series, and the pattern is not present in all of them. Maybe it is just a case, and not a pattern.

I am aware that richer models are possible, but my purpose here is to make the best possible specification of a AR model for inflation forecast, not to estimate other models.